# Batch rename in OSX, add @2x to all files ending with .png

Tags: ios, macos, terminal, rename

I would like to rename my images from .png to @2x.png. Is there some easy way to do this with the terminal?

Comment: I've voted to close because this question is way off topic. However. I use [Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With the help of Mark Setchell's answer I was able to solve this with the following one-liner:

```
for f in *.png; do NEW=${f%.png}@2x.png; mv ${f} "${NEW}"; done;
```

Edit: flopr was right, should work now

Answer (score 7):

Let me add something to the contribution.
A more generic,  multiple format (jpg, png, ..) and name "extension free" (pattern < name >@2x.< extension> ) one lined solution would be this:

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file%.*}@2x.${file##*.}"; done
```

This works like a charm. Hope it helps

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls *.png | while read f
do
    BASE=${f%.png}          # Strip ".png" off end
    NEW=${BASE}@2x.png      # Add in @2
    echo mv "$f" "${NEW}"   # Rename
done
```

Save it in a file called Add2x, then type:

```
chmod +x Add2x
./Add2x
```

When you have seen what it is going to do, remove the word "echo" so it actually does it.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. I finally solved it with this one liner: for f in *.png; do NEW=${f%.png}@2x.png; mv ${f} "${NEW}"; done;

Comment: @user1354603 then you must post this as an answer then you must accept it then only others =know what is the correct answer whoch helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 3):

macOS has a little known [built-in option to mass rename files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/353526/121968) since 10.10. No need for the Terminal, it's now as simple as selecting the files in Finder, right-click and choosing 'Rename *n* items ...':

[image]

Specify for Find: `.png` and for Replace with: `@2x.png` and click Rename.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A Recursive one liner that I use:

```
find -L . -type f -name "*.png" -exec bash -c 'echo "$0" "${0%.*}@2x.png"' {} \;
```

The -L for handling symbolic links...
type f is for finding files only

Swap 'echo' with 'mv' if you're happy with what the command will do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a simpler way, using the Perl `rename` tool...

```
rename 's/(.+)\.png/$1\@2x.png/i' *.png
```

That says... *"Replace one or more characters followed by `.png` by those same characters and `@2x.png`. Do this in a case-insensitive way (`i`) for all PNG files."*

The `rename` tool is easily installed with `homebrew` using `brew install rename`.