# How to batch rename all files with the same additional text?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, mv

Can `mv` or some other command in Unix append a string all files with a certain extension? Like I have a 3 files in a directory ending with `.txt`. Lets say following are they:

`one.txt`
`two.txt`
`three.txt`

I want to rename them to

`one_renamed.txt`
`two_renamed.txt`
`three_renamed.txt`

Is there a way we can batch rename all the files with the same additional text?

Comment: Easy with `rename` https://stackoverflow.com/a/37590221/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` loop and [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for file in *.txt; do mv "$file" "${file%.txt}_renamed.txt"; done
```

The result of the expansion `"${file%.txt}"` is the value of variable `file` with the string `.txt` deleted from the end.